# Почему не работает ни один проект на laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer, vagrant, homestead

Решил обновить homestead и вышла ошибка

> fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.

Обновллял командами: vagrant box update; composer update
После этого появилась такая ошибка на всех моих проектах. На новых(которые создаю через laravel new или composer create-project laravel/laravel), старых. Любой проект на laravel в homestead не работает и выдает такую ошибку. Однако php работает и тот же phpmyadmin работает исправно.
Пробовал удалять homestead, vagrant, php и ничего не помогло. Пробовал разные версии php (7.1, 7.2, 7.3)

Система mac os 10.14.5

Вот такая ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

Вот конфигурация:
[image: конфигурация]

В laravel.log вот такие записи:

[image: логи]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` помогает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удали Homestead и поставь valet, должно помочь.